# В каких случаях отображается ссылка "ответ дан"?

Tags: обсуждение

Наконец-то попался ответ со ссылкой

> Ответ дан 3 минуты назад

которая ведёт на историю ответа. В каком случае такая ссылка отображается?

Кстати, а почему ссылкой является только "3 минуты назад", тогда как в случае с "изменён" вся надпись - ссылка?

[image: Ответ дан 3 минуты назад]

Comment: Связанный вопрос: [Показывать ссылку на историю вопроса](//meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/q/2645/178988)

Comment: Похоже, ссылка появляется на общих ответах или ответах под общими вопросами

Comment: @Nofate, в этом какая-то особая задумка?

Comment: вы про ссылку или про само сообщение?

Comment: @Nofate, чем общие ответы отличаются от обычных настолько, чтобы не отображать для них время публикации, зато особым образом формировать блок об изменении?

Comment: Вероятно , ограниченностью размера плашки, в которую порой выводится много информации.

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/HpeaC1Y.png - пришлось бы в серый блок еще одну строчку втискивать

Comment: @Nofate, проценты занимают по ширине как аватарка, следовательно можно их разместить в одну строку с ником.